# How to use Custom type for @PathParam?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I want to use non spring bean class object as parameter for jersey web service class method. But it is giving missing dependency error at build time.

My code is:

```
@Component
@Path("/abcd")
public class ActorServiceEndpoint {

    @POST
    @Path("/test/{nonspringBean}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void addActor(@PathParam("nonspringBean") MyNonSpringBeanClass nonspringBean){
}

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing is path parameters come in String form. As per the specification, if we want the have a custom type  be injected as a `@PathParam`, the custom class, should have one of three things:

1. A public static `valueOf(String param)` that returns the type
2. A public static `fromString(String param)` that returns the type
3. Or a public constructor that accepts a String
4. Another option implement a [`ParamConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ParamConverter.html). You can see an example [here](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/blob/master/jaxrs/paramconverter/src/main/java/org/javaee7/jaxrs/paramconverter/MyBeanConverterProvider.java).

If you don't own the class (it's a third-party class that you can't change) then your only option is to use the `ParamConverter/ParamConverterProvider` pair.

In either of these cases you'll want to construct the instance accordingly by parsing the String either in the constructor or in one of the above mentioned methods. After doing this, the custom type can be made a method parameter with the annotation.

The same holds true for other params, such as `@FormParam`, `@HeaderParam`, `@QueryParam`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave a bit more details of the error you're getting, but I see two problems with your code snippet:

- <s>The correct Spring annotation is @PathVariable, @PathParam is probably from another package.</s> This doesn't apply as I guess you're using JAX-RS, not Spring annotations.
- I'm not sure what converters are applied to path variables, but in any case it would need to have one for MyNonSpringBeanClass. I would take a String parameter and then instantiate MyNonSpringBeanClass myself in the function body.